XStream empty collection is null
Im upgrading the xstream lib from 1.3 to 1.4.20.
Sometimes i'm deserilizing an empty collection with no wrapper. With version 1.4.20 that is turned into null instead of an empty collection, which is what I want.
How do I get an empty collection from and optional field not being present in the XML.
I have added the required
xstream.allowTypes(new Class[]{...})
I have tried to add the @XStreamImplicit annotation.
